# Reading XML via PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

Assume I have this XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<books>
  <book id="book1">
    <chapters>
      <chapter1>Begin</chapter1>
      <chapter2>mid</chapter2>
      <chapter3>end</chapter3>
    </chapters>
    <pages>352</pages>
  </book>
  <book id="book2">
    <chapters>
      <chapter1>woop</chapter1>
      <chapter2>doop</chapter2>
      <chapter3>goop</chapter3>
    </chapters>
    <pages>761</pages>
  </book>
</books>
```

Now I want to read this with PowerShell, e.g.:

```bsh
$file = "C:\path\books.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)

$books = $xml.books.book.id

foreach ($book in $books) {
    ...
}
```

In the loop I want to get the chapters of each book, so I tried this:

```bsh
$xml.books.book | ? {$_.id -eq $book} | select chapters.chapter1
```

but that didn't work. So I tried this instead:

```bsh
(xml.books.book | where $_.id -eq $book).chapters.chapter1
```

Both won't work for some reason. How can I get these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach didn't work, because `Select-Object` lets you select properties (`chapters`), but not nested properties (`chapters.chapter1`). You'd need to expand the properties and cascade the cmdlet calls to get the child property values:

```bsh
$xml.books.book |
    Where-Object {$_.id -eq $book} |
    Select-Object -Expand chapters |
    Select-Object -Expand chapter1
```

Your second approach didn't work, because you omitted the `$` from `$xml` and you didn't get the abbreviated `Where-Object` syntax right. If you want to use short `Where-Object` filter notation it's `<cmdlet> <property> <op> <value>` without the current object variable (`$_`):

```bsh
($xml.books.book | Where-Object id -eq $book).chapters.chapter1
```

otherwise you need the regular syntax:

```bsh
($xml.books.book | Where-Object {$_.id -eq $book}).chapters.chapter1
```

With that said, none of the approaches is very elegant. For your example scenario you could simply use dot-notation to get all `<chapter1>` values:

```bsh
$xml.books.book.chapters.chapter1
```

If you need more control it's usually more efficient to use [XPath expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx), though, e.g. if you want a list of all book IDs:

```bsh
$xml.SelectNodes('//book/@id') | Select-Object -Expand '#text'
```

or if you want to select the third chapter of the book with the ID "book2":

```bsh
$id = 'book2'
$xml.SelectSingleNode("//book[@id='$id']/chapters/chapter3").'#text'
```

Comment: Thanks! :) i tried the 3rd option and it worked. Grazi mille!